# Mouse over - display on screen message Java Application

Tags: java, swing, mouseover

I have built a program using Window Builder. I have used various Jbuttons, and would like to display a message such as "click here to add product" when the button is hovered over. I have added an event handler

```
        addButton.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {


        }
```

However i am unsure on the code needed within the FocusEvent to allow for this message to be displayed. I have looked at various methods such as MessageBox, but i don't think this is what i have been looking for.

Comment: Question edited: Eclipse tag removed (not relevant) and Swing tag added (very relevant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, don't use FocusListeners for this. Java Swing already has a built in tool for this, tool-tip. You will want to call `setToolTipText(...)` on your JButtons.